# How to post the parameter in ajax call of jquery datatable

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, datatables

As of now I am passing parameter along with URL in ajax call of data table.

But I want to pass it as `POST` method, please anyone one help me regarding parameter passing in post method, here's my trial code:

```
// Sending through GET
var $table = $('#example').dataTable( 
    "processing": true,
    "serverSide": true,
    "bDestroy": true,
    "bJQueryUI": true,
    "ajax": 'getResult.php?formName=afscpMcn&action=search&mcn_no='+mcnNum+'&cust_nm='+cust_num+'&emp_id='+emp+''
});
```

Comment: did you see this page? http://www.datatables.net/examples/server_side/post.html

Comment: just read the [manual](http://www.datatables.net/examples/server_side/post.html)

Comment: I want to pass the parameter like form name ,action and other parameters.. In that manual they have mention only column data

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Just pass it like a normal jQuery ajax in POST fashion.

The structure should look like this:

```
ajax: { type: 'POST', url: <path>, data: { your desired data } }
```

Example:

```
var $table = $('#example').dataTable( 
    "processing": true,
    "serverSide": true,
    "bDestroy": true,
    "bJQueryUI": true,
    "ajax": {
        'type': 'POST',
        'url': 'getResult.php',
        'data': {
           formName: 'afscpMcn',
           action: 'search',
           // etc..
        },
    }
});
```

In PHP, just access the POST indices as usual (just the straightforward approach):

`getResult.php`

```
$form_name = $_POST['formName'];
// the rest of your values ...
```

[DataTables manual entry](https://datatables.net/examples/server_side/post.html)

Comment: Hey Kevin, I am having trouble when the json return 0 results, imagine if the table has no entries... so when it returns a blank JSON I am getting error from datatable.. it is a default alert informing the JSON is in wrong format.. Do you know how can I deal with it?

Comment: @Sophie it's important that whatever you have in your response is still a valid structure that's acceptable to the format datatables need when you return it to client side. https://datatables.net/examples/server_side/simple.html even if it's zero rows.

Answer (score 10):

You can try this way:

```
$('#example').dataTable( {
  "ajax": {
    "url": "data.json",
    "data": function ( d ) {
        d.extra_search = $('#extra').val();
    }
  }
});
```

https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax.data

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#tbl").dataTable({
            oLanguage: {
                sProcessing: '<div id="loader"></div>'
            },
            bProcessing: true,
            "bServerSide": true,
            "iDisplayLength": pageSize,
            "sAjaxSource": " /PurchaseOrder/AddVendorItems", // url getData.php etc
            "fnServerData": function ( sSource, aoData, fnCallback, oSettings ) {
                aoData.push({ "name": "where", "value": ID +" AND ISNULL(IsFinal,0) = "+ ($("#chkFinal").bootstrapSwitch('state') == true ? 1 : 0) });
                aoData.push({"name": "PackIDFK", "value": $("#PackIDFK").val()}) //pushing custom parameters
                oSettings.jqXHR = $.ajax( {
                    "dataType": 'json',
                    "type": "POST",
                    "url": sSource,
                    "data": aoData,
                    "success": fnCallback
                } );
            } });
```

This is real time example.The aoData contains all the parameters which is required on server side and you can also push your own custom parameters