# Change Datatables ajax.url.load() type

Tags: php, ajax, datatable

I have a datatable that will be reloaded once the filters are changed. When a value is changed it will load the datatable. How can I pass the parameters in a POST using the ajax.url().load() instead of GET method.

I am inspecting the functions for ajax for datatables but I can't see any functions to rewrite the method. Here is the code I used for reloading the table.

```
UserFilterTable.ajax.url( url_request+"?"+$('form').serialize()).load(function() {
              $.unblockUI();
        });
```

Is there a way I can changed the type to POST?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to post the parameter in ajax call of jquery datatable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25505755/how-to-post-the-parameter-in-ajax-call-of-jquery-datatable)

Answer (score 0):

You can use ajax with post as below

```
$.post('url_request', $('#form').serialize())
```